# What does the __default__ prefix mean in ng-inspector?

Tags: angularjs

What exactly does the `__default__` prefix mean in ng-inspector as shown below?

[image: ng-inspector __default__ prefix]

I am trying to access this value and I'm not quite sure how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The extension certainly didn't add that prefix, if it shows up in ng-inspector, something else added that to your model.